# Rails 導入の際のエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://railsguides.jp/getting_started.html
上記urlのチュートリアルにそってrailsのアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、「5.2最初のフォーム」にてnew.html.erbの中身を
`<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`
に変更する部分でsyntax errorが吐き出されました。
構文エラーなのでform forの書き方について調べてみて
http://www.sejuku.net/blog/13163、
このサイトを見つけたのですが
`<%= form_for article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`
や
`<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`
に書き直してみてもsyntax errorが出続けます。
この一文はどのように書き直すのが正しいのでしょうか？
それとも何か別の原因があるのでしょうか？
railsについて詳しい方がいたら返信お願いします。

OSはwindows7、rubyは2.4.2、railsは5.1.4です。
出てきたエラーの内容は以下のとおりです。

```
blog(アプリケーションのフォルダ)/app/views/articles/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':' pend= form_for @article. url: articles_path do |f| @output_ ^ blog/app/views/articles/new.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^
```

Comment: new.html.erb の内容を追記してください。

Comment: エラーメッセージは最初のコードの状態のものにしてください。また、コードやエラーメッセージはコードとして表示されるようマークアップしてください。エディタの"{}"ボタンかCtrl+Kです。

Comment: わざわざ見ていただき申し訳ございません。リファレンスを見ながら色々書き換えていたら<%= form_for :article, :url =>articles_path do |f| %>で解決できました。次質問する際は、最初のコードのエラーメッセージにするなど気をつけさせてもらいます。返信ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決された場合は、その解決法をコメントではなく回答として投稿下さい。（自分自身で回答を投稿できます）

Answer (score -1):

リファレンスを見ながら色々書き換えていたら`<%= form_for :article, :url =>articles_path do |f| %>`で解決できました。